# What is the formula for Usage Rate?

Tags: terminology, corpora

I read about a concept called the "usage rate" (proposed by Juliand and Chang-Rodriguez). It's a method for calculating the frequency of a word in a corpus. What exactly is the "usage rate" and what is the formula for calculating a word's usage rate?

Comment: How about just counting the number of occurrences of each word you're interested in?

Comment: because I want to know more about the "usage rate" in a corpus. I edited the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: all the papers I've read just count up the tokens and then divide by corpus size, and scale it to a nice round number (usually 1000 or 1000000), so usage rate is words/thousand or words/million.